# selected radio button values to display in textbox and dropdown menu using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Following link [Jquery for pass selected radio button value on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394988/jquery-for-pass-selected-radio-button-value-on-button-click) .It is working properly for me.

In the above question i want to pass the values(and display in dropdown box and textbox) in radio button click not on button click..How it is possible.

Comment: Could you post the JavaScript code you've tried to attempt this?

Comment: $("input[type='radio']").click(function()
{alert("insde")} .it doent alert anything on radio button click

Comment: have you tried 
`$("input[type='radio']").on('click',function() {alert("insde")}`  
instead?

Comment: it is also  not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
"<input type="radio" name="joblist" onclick="myfunc(this);" id= ' + value.jobid + 'value=' + value.jobid + '/>"

function  myfunc(ele){
 var $tr=$(ele).parent().parent(); ....
 //the rest of the code
}
```

to select the one you want.

```
 $("#OS option").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==os)
      $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    else
       $(this).removeAttr('selected');
 });
```

Comment: but i put like this may be the code is working but nothing happend in the radio button click

Comment: when you create the radio button try adding an onclick function in it like `<input type="radio" name="joblist" onclick="myfunc(this);" id= ' + value.jobid + 'value=' + value.jobid + '/>` and put the code inside the myfunc

Comment: check the code in the answer for `myfunc`, rewrite the `myfunc` like that, you have missed the parameter

Comment: but one prolem happening is  the dropdown list automatically adds its selected radio button values

Comment: which one? if you don't want to add automatically the values in selectbox just remove the code for that in the function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36102/discussion-between-psl-and-rps)

Comment: Helllo,the above modified code is not working.it works first time only.that means i have  5more radio buttons while selecting any one of them the values are diapying in the corresponding dropddown menu's later select any one the radio its value does not seen as selected in dripdown and textboxex.

Comment: @Psl is the onclick function getting executed? try alerting something in the onclick function.

Comment: yes it is working now when i use `$("#OS").val(os);
    $("#testscriptlist").val(testscriptlist)` like this...thank you

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nmzmp/)**

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {

            alert($(this).val());

    });
});
```

and the radio button HTML

```
<input type="radio" value="male" name="sex" />male
<input type="radio" value="female" name="sex" />female
```

Hope this helps, thank you